# mysql trigger update a record when certain record value contained in new inserted record from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, nested, gammu

I'm new here and really need help. Work around it for days and haven't met the solution. I work with gammu.

I have these tables

table inbox

```
+--------------+
| TextDecoded  |
+--------------+
|xx200.001,00xx|
|xx300.001,00xx|
+--------------+
```

table balance

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| costumer_id | refill_balance | refill_nominal | status     |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
|          1  | 2000001        | 300.001,00     |    verified|
|          1  | 2000001        | 200.001,00     |not_verified|
+-------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

table costumer

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| costumer_id | name           | balance        |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+
|          1  | bond           | 3000001        |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

The scenario is:

1. when there's incoming message, it will be saved in inbox.TextDecoded
2. The new incoming message will be checked whether it contains balance.refill_nominal or not
3. If no.2 is true then balance.status will be verified
4. If no.3 done then the value of costumer.balance will be added with the value of balance.refill_balance

I have tried this trigger for the balance.status update

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER verify_refill AFTER INSERT ON inbox
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE balance
SET status='verified'
WHERE refill_nominal=(SELECT balance.refill_nominal FROM balance JOIN inbox ON NEW.inbox.TextDecoded LIKE CONCAT('%',balance.refill_nominal,'%') AND balance.status='not_verified';
END $$
```

And try this trigger for adding the costumer.balance

```
DELIMITER
CREATE TRIGGER add_balance AFTER UPDATE ON balance
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE costumer
SET balance=OLD.balance+NEW.refill_balance
WHERE
costumer_id=NEW.costumer_id
END $$
```

None of them work. Please help me..

Comment: You say the triggers you have don't work. What do they do? Do you her an error message? If so, what is it?